# Get time to a location

Tags: android, android-location

I;m currently using Location.distanceTo(Location) to get how far it is to a location. IS it also possible to get the time it takes to get to a location by E.G driving just using two Locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible with just two `Location` objects. For that you need to use some service(Google Navigation, etc) to figure it out for you.

Unless you ignore all traffic rules and assume an average speed. Then you could just spit out a number, but it probably won't be very accurate.

Comment: What service do I need for getting the driving time? I can find stuff on laying driving direction of a map but nothing about just getting the time.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) looks promising.